# Decorating Functions

Tags: python

I'm a python beginner and I struggle with a somewhat easy concept of functional programming. I simply can not see why the nested function (see example below) would even be called. This is quite hard to explain.

```
func3 = func1(func2)
```

Here I call `func1` with the positional argument `func2`. All fair and well. `func1` returns a nested function. But when I run the code the function `nest1`has been executed even though I've only called `func1` (I dont see why this should execute the nested function). `func1` should not do more than returning a function without printing anything. Can someone explain this to me?

```
def func2():

  def nest2():
      print('Nest2')

  nest2()
  return nest2


def func1(func):

   def nest1():
       print('Nest1')
       func()

   return nest1


func3 = func1(func2)

func3()
```

If I call a simple function with a nested function the inner function is not executed. See below:

```
def new_func():
   def inner():
       print(1)
   return inner

new_func()
```

Comment: You are calling `nest1`, though. `func3` and `nest1` are the same object, and you're calling `func3`.

Comment: yeah. I just realized that ... what a stupid question from my side ... thanks, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func1()` returns the method `nest1` (without executing it), so your call `func3 = func1(func2)` returns `nest1` and assigns it to `func3`.

The next line you are executing whatever is assigned to `func3` - which is the method `nest1`. In other words, the line `func3()` is executing the function `nest1`, and causing the text to print.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I run the code the function nest1 has been executed even though I've only called func1 (I dont see why this should execute the nested function). Func 1 should not do more than returning a function without printing anything. Can someone explain this to me?

When you do this:

```
func3 = func1(func2)
```

You pass the function `func2` into the function `func1`. Inside of `func1`, you define a function `nest1` that calls the function passed in. This function is then returned and becomes the value of `func3`. The only thing `func1` does is create the `nest1` function, and return it. When `func3` is called, you actually called the function defined inside of `func1`, `nest1`.

> If I call a simple function with a nested function the inner function is not executed.

The reason your second example did not work as expected, is because calling `new_func` does not call `inner`, it only *creates* `inner` and returns it. This is the same case as above. Calling `func1` did not call `nest1`, it simply created `nest1` and returned it. You had to explitly call `nest1` (`func3()`). Likewise, you need to call the function returned from `new_func` explicitly:

```
new_func()()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the final example, you need to call the function that is being returned with an extra `()`:

```
def new_func():
   def inner():
      print(1)
   return inner

new_func()()
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Body of `func2` is:

```
def nest2():
    print('Nest2')

nest2()

return nest2
```

And so body of `func1(func2)` is:

```
print('Nest1')

def nest2():
    print('Nest2')

nest2()

return nest2
```

The last piece we get by replacing `func` with body of `func2` in body of `nest1`.